# Windows 7 losing programs from desktop?

Tags: windows-7

How do I recover program icons no longer on my desktop nor Start menu since I installed Windows 7. All programs are still on the HDD but not on the Start menu or Desktop

Comment: Are they in the recycle bin? Are all icons gone?

Comment: When you get started face this problem?

Comment: Did you have an existing Windows installation that you upgraded to Windows 7?  Or is this a fresh install and applications stop appearing?

Comment: As @BBlake shares the same thought, have you recently upgraded Windows (from Vista onwards) and now the entries are missing? Unlike the answer from agc93 below (which is helpful, of course) I believe you shouldn't go straight into using his answer. I fear you may have some corruption somewhere as both desktop shortcuts and Start menu entries are now just "missing" - they go missing if you manually delete them, uninstall the program, have malware or have some corruption in the OS causing items to no longer be seen.

Answer (score 5):

If you find the *.exe on your HDD, you can right-click, choose Send To... and then select Desktop (create shortcut) to send a shortcut to the desktop. You can also copy a shortcut into your `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` folder if you only want it displayed when you are logged in.